# how to create a branch in clearcase with GUI operation only?

Tags: clearcase

I searched for a while and tried to find a way to create a branch in clearcase, but cleartool commands are used in all the articles I found.
I'm just curious that is there any other way to use GUI operation only?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Of course, you can create a branch through the GUI.

- If you are using UCM:

  - you can open the ClearCase project explorer,
  - define a new stream,
  - create a view on it,
  - open the ClearCase explorer
  - checkout any file and select its version tree

You will see a new branch created for that file

[image: ProjectExplorer]

---

- If you are using base ClearCase

  - open your ClearCase Explorer
  - select "properties" on your view
  - modify the config spec of your view

```
element * /main/LATEST
```

into:

```
element * /main/0 -mkbranch aNewBranch
element * /main/LATEST -mkbranch aNewBranch
```

And when you checkout a file, you will see "`aNewBranch`" in its version tree.

Note: in base ClearCase, you may need to create the "branch type" first, before being able to use it in a config spec.
Again, there is a GUI for that: the **type explorer**. (`Start > Programs > Rational ClearCase> Type Explorer`)

- Open it,
- select the right Vob where your elements will use that branch

[image: Base ClearCase]

- select "branch type",
- and create your branch type "`aNewBranch`".

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed reply.
Unfortunatedly I'm using base ClearCase. I managed to create a branch type and then I have to type in the config spec.
I feel IBM's software is weird and I felt the same for IBM Lotus Notes: not straight forward.

Comment: @Fei: I hear you about the weirdness of ClearCase ;) And Lotus Notes (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238177/worst-ui-youve-ever-used/238191#238191)