# Release multiple labels in clearcase

Tags: version-control, branch, clearcase

I am using ClearCase. I have created a snapshot view to release two issues.

- For issue1 I have created `Label1`.
- For issue2 I have created `Label2` on the same branch.

Now problem is `Label2` shows changes from both issue1 and issue2.

Is there a way we can avoid this, so that `Label2` has changes only for issue2 and `Label1` has changes only for issue1?

Is this possible, or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two separate issues that you want to consider separately, it is best to isolate them in their own respective branches.

[Create two branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2110226/6309) from a common ancestor (a point in time *before* working on either issue)

- in branch `Issue1`, report your modifications dedicated to issue 1: you can then set the label `Label1`.
- in branch `Issue2`, report your modifications dedicated to issue 2: you can then set the label `Label2` without worrying about issue 1.

---

If having two branches (and two views) is not practical, then [you would have to look for all versions *not* labelled Issue1 in order to set your Label2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3334547/6309):

```
cleartool find . -cview -version !lbtype(Label1) -exec "cleartool mklabel Label2 \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

Or you would need to find versions labelled both `Label1` and `Label2`, and remove the `Label2` one:

```
cleartool find . -cview -version "lbtype(Label1) && lbtype(Label2)" -exec "cleartool rmlabel Label2 \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```